# error on typing "pip install --upgrade gensim" on cmd

Tags: python

while typing "pip install --upgrade gensim" on cmd i am getting error pls provide solution to this.the error is as follows:

> pip install --upgrade gensim Collecting gensim Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Subash\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line
>   215, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)   File "C:\Users\Subash\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py",
>   line 335, in run
>       wb.build(autobuilding=True)   File "C:\Users\Subash\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749,
>   in build
>       self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)   File "C:\Users\Subash\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line
>   380, in prepare_files
>       ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))   File "C:\Users\Subash\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line
>   554, in _prepare_file
>       require_hashes   File "C:\Users\Subash\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py",
>   line 278, in populate_link
>       self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)   File "C:\Users\Subash\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 465,
>   in find_requirement
>       all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)   File "C:\Users\Subash\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 423,
>   in find_all_candidates
>       for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):   File "C:\Users\Subash\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 568,
>   in _get_pages
>       page = self._get_page(location)   File "C:\Users\Subash\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 683,
>   in _get_page
>       return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)   File "C:\Users\Subash\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 811,
>   in get_page
>       inst = cls(resp.content, resp.url, resp.headers)   File "C:\Users\Subash\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 731,
>   in **init**
>       namespaceHTMLElements=False, TypeError: parse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transport_encoding'

please help me

Comment: was `gensim` forst installed with `pip` or with `conda`?

Comment: first i tried with anaconda